# error: Dependency is not of a valid type: element 1 of nativeBuildInputs for nix-shell

Tags: nix

I am working on a simple nix environment where I want to run a script which generates shell script output that should (according to a complex web of rules) initialize a bunch of env vars in my env.

However, I am taken aback by a cryptic error message.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. (In general: How do I define a derivation that I then can run as part of my shell initialization?)

#### Code

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
pkgs.mkShell {
  packages = with pkgs; [
    pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
      deps = [];
      buildInputs = [];
      src = "hi";
      name = "hello";
      stdenv = "./";

    }
  ];

  shellHook = "echo " + "hi;";
}
```

#### Result

```bash
$ nix-shell "./dev-env.nix"
```

```
error:
       … while calling the 'derivationStrict' builtin

         at /builtin/derivation.nix:9:12: (source not available)

       … while evaluating derivation 'nix-shell'
         whose name attribute is located at /nix/store/ka3vmkgvsn6cj8dywj7n1xl3bm54gxm7-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:352:7

       … while evaluating attribute 'nativeBuildInputs' of derivation 'nix-shell'

         at /nix/store/ka3vmkgvsn6cj8dywj7n1xl3bm54gxm7-source/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:396:7:

          395|       depsBuildBuild              = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 0) 0;
          396|       nativeBuildInputs           = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 0) 1;
             |       ^
          397|       depsBuildTarget             = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 0) 2;

       error: Dependency is not of a valid type: element 1 of nativeBuildInputs for nix-shell
```

Comment: What do you expect `stdenv = "./";` or `src = "hi";` to mean/do? Why do you consider either of these correct? (To be clear, `stdenv.mkDerivation`, unlike `builtins.derivation`, implies a bunch of conventions; attributes are expected to have specific types, and neither `src` nor `stdenv` is expected to be a simple string).

Comment: If you want to see exactly what ended up at the beginning of the `nativeBuildInputs` array, the interactive debugger added to newer versions of Nix is your friend; that said, I _suspect_ that it's trying to pull something out of stdenv.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will investigate soon!

Comment: As for the more general question you asked, I'd want to know more about what you're trying to wrap in that derivation. If you have a shell script with no dependencies that's in your source tree as `sourceme`, for example, I'd set `shellHook = '' . ${./sourceme} '';` and that would be enough; no actual derivation wrapper needed.